# Different results between interactive and compiled Haskell (Project Euler 20)

Tags: haskell

I'm doing problem 20 on Project Euler - finding the sum of the digits of 100! (factorial, not enthusiasm).

Here is the program I wrote:

```
import Data.Char

main = print $ sumOfDigits (product [1..100])

sumOfDigits :: Int -> Int
sumOfDigits n = sum $ map digitToInt (show n)
```

I compiled it with `ghc -o p20 p20.hs` and executed it, getting only `0` on my command line.

Puzzled, I invoked `ghci` and ran the following line:

`sum $ map Data.Char.digitToInt (show (product [1..100]))`

This returned the correct answer. Why didn't the compiled version work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is the type signature

```
sumOfDigits :: Int -> Int
sumOfDigits n = sum $ map digitToInt (show n)
```

use

```
sumOfDigits :: Integer -> Int
```

and you will get the same thing as in GHCi (what you want).

`Int` is the type for machine word sized "ints" while, `Integer` is the type for mathematically correct, arbitrary precision `Integers`.

if you type

```
:t product [1..100]
```

into GHCi you will get something like

```
product [1..100] :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
```

that is, for ANY type that has instances of the Enum and Num type classes, `product [1..100]` could be a value of that type

```
product [1..100] :: Integer
```

should return 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000 which is far bigger than your machine is likely to be able to represent as a word on your machine.  Probably, because of roll over

```
product [1..100] :: Int
```

will return 0

given this, you might think

```
sum $ map Data.Char.digitToInt (show (product [1..100]))
```

would not type check, because it has multiple possible incompatible interpretations.  But, in order to be usable as a calculator, Haskell defaults to using `Integer` in situations like this, thus explaining your behavior.

For the same reason, if you had NOT given `sumOfDigits` an explicit type signature it would have done what you want, since the most general type is

```
sumOfDigits :: Show a => a -> Int
```